# CSS Zoom sizing and table cell contents

Tags: css

How can I get Internet Explorer to resize table cells based on zoomed content inside them?

Chrome shows this:

[image]

IE11 shows this - the label didn't move based on the zoomed content next to it:

[image]

Sample code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>here's a label</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<style>
input[type=radio] {
    zoom: 400%
}
</style>
```

Here's a jsfildle showing the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/SKjP3/1/

Comment: and firefox doesn't support zoom

Answer (score 0):

you can use the CSS transform property to change your radio button like this:

```
input[type=radio] {       
  -webkit-transform: scale(4);
  -moz-transform:    scale(4);
  -ms-transform:     scale(4);
  -o-transform:      scale(4);
  transform:         scale(4);     
  margin-right:20px;
}
```

this will magnify by 4=400% in all browser, the result is maybe not what you expect, because it depends on browsers rendering

if you add

```
label{ margin-left:20px;}
```

then the label will show in all browser in the same position, check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SKjP3/3/)

Comment: I tried that and in chrome you get correct spacing AND a big margin.